# UIView with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer doesn't resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, avfoundation

I need to have a custom camera with the bottom layer as the camera, and a layer on top of it as a PNG picture with a hole in it so you could see a part of the camera through the hole. Both layers should be in the size of the PNG photo, fit the size of the screen, and maintain the PNG's original aspect ratio.

In the storyboard I have a `UIView` to present the camera, and a `UIImageView` to present the PNG on top of it, both with Auto-layout to the superview.

I've managed to get the PNG right as I wanted by using this code (works fine):

```
UIImage *passedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:self.photoTitle];
CGRect imageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, passedImage.size.width, passedImage.size.height);
self.imageView.frame = imageBounds;
[self.imageView setImage:passedImage];
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

I got the camera displaying in the `UIView` by using `AVFoundation` (`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`) with this code:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
CALayer *rootLayer = [self.cameraFeedView layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
CGRect frame = self.cameraFeedView.frame;
[previewLayer setFrame:frame];
previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds;
[rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];
```

This way I have the PNG in the center of the screen as I wanted but the camera behind it expands to the bounds of the screen while I need the camera view to be the same size as the image and exactly behind it.

I've tried to resize the `UIView` the same way I resized the `UIImageView` but instead of shrinking the view to fit the screen it gets the PNG's original size (larger than the screen) and flows out of the screen.

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time but haven't found an answer yet. I'm pretty new to objective-c programming. Please help me, I'm desperate.

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution to your problem.

You want to show a AVCaptureVideo on the exact area where image bounds, but behind the image. So I think you are trying to prepare some framing functionality on video.

Here is the solution. Please call this code after setting your image to UIImage. You will require a imageScale method which I've mentioned following this code.

Here, your previewLayer size will be set according to image fits to UIImageView. make sure you set your image AspectFit as you requires.

```
//Get ratio of UIImage size on UIImageview.
CGSize sizeMade = [self imageScale];

//Change UIImageview frame according to image size.
float fHeight = passedImage.image.size.height*sizeMade.height;
float fWidth = passedImage.image.size.width*sizeMade.width;

CGRect tFrame = previewLayer.frame;
tFrame.size.height = fHeight;
tFrame.size.width = fWidth;
previewLayer.frame = tFrame;
```

Function to get ratio of image scale to UIImageView.

```
- (CGSize)imageScale{

    CGFloat sx = _imageviewAboutToZoom.frame.size.width / _imageAboutToZoom.size.width;
    CGFloat sy = _imageviewAboutToZoom.frame.size.height / _imageAboutToZoom.size.height;
    CGFloat s = 1.0;
    switch (_imageviewAboutToZoom.contentMode) {
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
            s = fminf(sx, sy);
            return CGSizeMake(s, s);
            break;

        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
            s = fmaxf(sx, sy);
            return CGSizeMake(s, s);
            break;

        case UIViewContentModeScaleToFill:
            return CGSizeMake(sx, sy);

        default:
            return CGSizeMake(s, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either I didn't understand your instructions or it doesn't work ):